# How to catch empty lines in user input for Scala?

Tags: scala

Consider the following code

```
val sc = new java.util.Scanner (System.in)
while (sc.hasNext()) {
  var temp = sc.nextLine()
  println(temp.nonEmpty)
  println (temp)
}
```

whenever I press `enter` with empty line the program simply waits for next input to happen and does not execute the statement inside

For example

```
input: 
<enter>
<enter>
1
```

cause

```
output:
<space>
false
<space>
false
1
true
```

I am trying to make user enter a list of lines, and exit on empty lines

eg.

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
<enter> // -> will exit
```

How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a bit more idiomatic:

```
Iterator.continually(scala.io.StdIn.readLine).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).foreach(line =>
   println(s"read $line")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `if (temp.isEmpty) sys.exit(1)`